# Pass data between ViewController and TableVC with NSUserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

How to pass the state of a `NSUserDefault` between several Classes in `Swift`? 
In this case I want to pass this state between one `TableViewController`, where you change the state on the switch, and one initial VC. 
Here is a little model to understand...[image]

I used this to set the state with the switch:

```
@IBAction func changeTouchIDState(sender: AnyObject) {

    if TouchIDSwitch.on {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "State")

    } else {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "State")

    }
}
```

If the state = true, the initial VC should ask about the Authentication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question need little more explanation, I don't understand why you want to pass the value as you are already storing in `NSUserDefaults` which you can access in any `class` of your app.

**As per my understanding to your problem I'm suggesting the solution:**

As you already storing State in NSUserDefaults so before presenting initial VC check `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("State")` if its true, ask authentication otherwise don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know that NSUserDefault is active in all classes....

Answer (score 0):

After setting the bool, you should synchronise:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Then, you can access that value with:

```
func boolForKey(_ defaultName: String) -> Bool
```

Comment: No, there is no need to call `synchronize`. You can access the value without calling `synchronize`.